How to take 頂きましょう?
The characters are talking about love. In the previews line, 天道 asks

天道「おや。女性への理解が深い伊波さんのご登場ですね」
伊波「そこそこな、そこそこ」
恋愛指南をご教授頂きましょう？　とばかりの天道に伊波も、左手の親指と人差し指を開いて見せた。その距離は３センチ程度か。
天道「おやあ。今度しっかり聞かないと駄目ですね。知らない伊波さんの一面は楽しそうです」

I'm a bit unsure on how to take 頂きましょう here. I assume it's either akin "should I have you teach me about love" or "Should I teach you about love?" From context I can gather it's the second but I don't quite get why 頂き is used here?

The first option is the correct interpretation. 天道 is admiring 伊波's knowledge about women in the first line, so 天道 is (probably jokingly) saying he will learn love advice from 伊波. 頂く is the humble verb for もらう, so the literal translation is something like "May I humbly receive your teachings on love advice?"
